# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'range' and 'int' (needed output given bellow)

Tags: python

**Input**:

```
listNum = [range(51)]
evNum_squares= [num * num for num in listNum if num // 2 == 0]
odNum_squares = [num * num for num in listNum if num // 2 != 0]

print(odNum_squares, evNum_squares)
```

**Output**:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "E:/Python/Project_Data_Structure *List* Slicing.py", line 2, in 
> evNum_squares= [num * num for num in listNum if num // 2 == 0]
> File "E:/Python/Project_Data_Structure *List* Slicing.py", line 2, in 
> evNum_squares= [num * num for num in listNum if num // 2 == 0]
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'range' and 'int'

**Needed Output:**

```
[ Input: [1,2,3………,50]
Output:
even number squares: [4 16, .......2304]
odd number squares: [1,9,25, ........2401]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listNum = range(51)
evNum_squares= [num * num for num in listNum if num // 2 == 0]
odNum_squares = [num * num for num in listNum if num // 2 != 0]

print(odNum_squares, evNum_squares)
```

Comment: While this answer may answer the question it would be good if you explained the code a bit, e.g. why it is built that way, how it works etc.

Comment: '[ **Input:** [1,2,3………,50]'
**Output:**
'even number squares: [4 16, .......2304]'
'odd number squares: [1,9,25, ........2401]'

Comment: i have edited the Question with the result needed

Answer (score 0):

Range by itself creates an iterable. So putting that in a list is unesaccary.
Try this.

```
listNum = range(51)
evNum_squares= [num * num for num in listNum if num // 2 == 0]
odNum_squares = [num * num for num in listNum if num // 2 != 0]

print(odNum_squares, evNum_squares)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using one of the following methods.

- `listNum = range(51)`
- `listNum = [i for i in range(51)]`
- `listNum = list(range(51))`
- `listNum = [*range(51)]`